# jekyll github page multiple post type connection

Tags: github, jekyll

Recently building my github page with Jekyll.
I wanted to have a few types of post, mainly blog and study note.
I found a way to make the url the way I want them to be, however the connection is way off.

I used 2 methods, first I tried with create subfolder under _post folder

```
-_post
 --blog
  ---first_post.md
 --studynote
  ---first_note.md
```

I also tried create _post folder as subfolder:

```
-blog
 --_post
  ---first_post.md
-studynote
 --_post
  ---first_note.md
```

but no matter how I put them, they only show up in username.github.io/blog/
however their url is correct.

What should I look into to gain better understanding to Jekyll's syntax? Ruby?

Comment: The correct folder name is `_posts` (plural) not `_post` (singular)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting your posts in subfolders, use categories. From the [jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/#predefined-variables-for-posts):

> Instead of placing posts inside of folders, you can specify one or more categories that the post belongs to. When the site is generated the post will act as though it had been set with these categories normally. Categories (plural key) can be specified as a YAML list or a space-separated string.

This way, you can write a post in the _posts folder, set its category to either `blog` or `studynote` (or whatever you want it to be) and then that post will show up at username.github.io/category/post-permalink.

Also make sure that `baseurl` in your config file isn't set to `/blog`, because then everything on your site will appear under /blog. Hopefully this helps!